# How to convert an integer to a string portably?

Tags: c, portability, itoa

I was looking for a way to convert an integer to a string in a portable manner (portable among at least Windows & Linux and x86 and x86_64) and I though `itoa(X)` to be standard just like `atoi(1)`.

But I read the following in the Wikipedia entry:

> The itoa function is a widespread non-standard extension to the standard C programming language. It cannot be portably used, as it is not defined in any of the C language standards; however, compilers often provide it through the header   while in non-conforming mode, because it is a logical counterpart to the standard library function atoi.

So I'd like to know if there is any way to do it in a portable manner or not. In case I have to write my own function, which things do I have to be careful with?

Comment: while itoa isn't _officially_ portable, I doubt you will ever run into a problem with it.  and if you do, it's a very easy function to write.

Comment: You could always implement your own :P

Answer (score 1):

Most often you just use printf("%d");

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf

You can use sprintf if you need it in a buffer, but how often do you convert to a string and not write it to a file or output device?

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't doing this terribly often, how about a runtime library routine that writes a few numbers to memory, analyzes the results and stores an encoding type?  From then on you just switch on your "encoding type" to select which conversion routine to use.